# why chrome open's without com/edu/org suffixes?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, url

This address continues with company domain name like `http://redmine.company.com.tr` but somehow chrome can resolve when I enter this `http://redmine`. I wonder how chrome does this while firefox, edge, opera can't.

Or please tell me how I can inspect this.

[image]

**Edit:**
nslookup results like I attached below. I wonder how these url requests are being solved by chrome?

[image]

When I ran for bitbucket I receieve the bitbucket page with https scheme:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me, so it has to be something on your side, likely a Chrome extension if it works only in Chrome.  E.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-alias/nelckmdlallhkgniidbfafekeldjnakb allows this

Comment: Does this happens with any ISP and any type of network connection? Does this happens in incognito mode without any extension enabled? Is your computer administered by you or by someone else?

Comment: What happens when you check DNS for this partial domain name?

Comment: @music2myear do you mean that did I check using by nslookup command or what?

Comment: @Rubén I've run nslookup query and put it into question message.

Answer (score 0):

Your network likely advertises `company.com.tr` as a "domain search suffix" through DHCP<sup>1</sup>, which the OS automatically adds to any single-label name (and sometimes to all names, uselessly).

All browsers should be capable of doing this (as it relies on an OS-level feature); some just refuse to. For example, Firefox will accept `http://srv01` but not `srv01` alone.

The screenshot looks like Windows – run `ipconfig` or `ipconfig /all` to check the currently active domain search suffixes.

---

<sup>1</sup> The domain suffix can also be configured manually, e.g. through `sysdm.cpl` system-wide or through `ncpa.cpl` per interface; every Windows system joined to an Active Directory domain will have the AD domain set up as the system-wide search suffix. Linux systems might have it defined in `/etc/resolv.conf` or through `resolvectl`.